# RadioButton inside grid column not showing selected values in Ext js 4.0

Tags: extjs

My code is here don't know what I'm doing wrong. my radio button is not group radio button its single button in separate column and if i select once i couldn't  deselect it again

```
dataIndex: 'Regex',
flex     : 1,
text     : 'Regex',
hideable : false,
sortable :false,
editor: { 
    xtype     : 'radiofield',
    name      : 'Regex',
    //boxLabel: 'Checked',
    inputValue: 'Checked'
},
listeners: {
    //display the selected radiofield value
    change: function(obj, value){ 
        alert(this.getValue().Regex);
    }
}
```

Comment: than use checkbox instead of radio

Comment: I totally agree with mega6382. use checkbox and manage the uncheck of the other checkboxes (onchange) and synchronise the store after having unchecked the others. The store has to have `autoSync: false`

Comment: i can't requirement is radio button

Comment: lets forget about deselect radio button just i want solution for displaying selected radio button value and store it and pass to php

Comment: One idea would be to use checkboxes and apply the radio cls to them inside this grid.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `AfterRender` listner of the radio button. For example,

```
var setIsChecked = function(field,store) {              
            if(field.ownerCt.record.data.isChecked)
            {                                     
                field.setValue(true);
            }
        }
```

and

```
<Listeners>
   <AfterRender Handler="setIsChecked(this,#{strQueries})"></AfterRender>
</Listeners>
```